# How to create a non-persistent Elixir/SQLAlchemy object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

Because of legacy data which is not available in the database but some external files, I want to create a SQLAlchemy object which contains data read from the external files, but isn't written to the database if I execute `session.flush()`

My code looks like this:

```
try:
  return session.query(Phone).populate_existing().filter(Phone.mac == ident).one()
except:
  return self.createMockPhoneFromLicenseFile(ident)

def createMockPhoneFromLicenseFile(self, ident):
  # Some code to read necessary data from file deleted....
  phone = Phone()
  phone.mac = foo
  phone.data = bar
  phone.state = "Read from legacy file"
  phone.purchaseOrderPosition = self.getLegacyOrder(ident)
  # SQLAlchemy magic doesn't seem to work here, probably because we don't insert the created
  # phone object into the database. So we set the id fields manually.
  phone.order_id = phone.purchaseOrderPosition.order_id
  phone.order_position_id = phone.purchaseOrderPosition.order_position_id
  return phone
```

Everything works fine except that on a `session.flush()` executed later in the application SQLAlchemy tries to write the created Phone object to the database (which fortunately doesn't succeed, because phone.state is longer than the data type allows), which breaks the function which issues the flush.

Is there any way to prevent SQLAlchemy from trying to write such an object?

**Update**

While I didn't find anything on

```
using_mapper_options(save_on_init=False)
```

in the Elixir documentation (maybe you can provide a link?), it seemed to me worth a try (I would have preferred a way to prevent a single instance from being written instead of the whole entity).

At first it seemed that the statement has no effect and I suspected my SQLAlchemy/Elixir versions to be too old, but then I found out that the connection to the PurchaseOrderPosition entity (which I didn't modify) made with

```
phone.purchaseOrderPosition = self.getLegacyOrder(ident)
```

causes the phone object to be written again. If I remove the statement, everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
import elixir
elixir.options_defaults['mapper_options'] = { 'save_on_init': False }
```

to prevent `Entity` instances which you instantiate being auto-added to the session. Ideally, this should be done as early as possible in your code. You can also do this on a per-entity basis, via `using_mapper_options(save_on_init=False)` - see the Elixir documentation for more details.

**Update:**

See [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlelixir/browse_thread/thread/45d88864325bd9da/7575288f4354401b?lnk=gst&q=save_on_init#7575288f4354401b) on the Elixir mailing list indicating that this is the solution.

Also, as Ants Aasma points out, you can use cascade options on the Elixir relationship to set up cascade options in SQLAlchemy. See [this page](http://elixir.ematia.de/apidocs/elixir.relationships.html#manytoone) for more details.

Comment: Please see the update section in my question for my comments to your answer.

Comment: In addition to avoiding implicit Session.add on object creation you'll also need to avoid cascades on relationships. See the cascade documentation in SQLAlchemy docs if Elixir doesn't document it, Elixir should still allow it to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sqlalchemy doesn't, by default.

Consider the following self-contained example code.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

e = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base = declarative_base(bind=e)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50))

# create the empty table and a session
Base.metadata.create_all()
s = create_session(bind=e, autoflush=False, autocommit=False)

# assert the table is empty
assert s.query(User).all() == []

# create a new User instance but don't save it to database:
u = User()
u.name = 'siebert'
# I could run s.add(u) here but I won't

s.flush()
s.commit()

# assert the table is still empty
assert s.query(User).all() == []
```

So I'm not sure what's implicity adding your instances to the session. Normally you have to manually call `s.add(u)` to make it go to the session. I'm not familiar with elixir so perhaps this is some elixir trickery... Maybe you could remove it from the session, by using [`session.expunge()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/sessions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expunge).

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I came across a similar issue, in my case in sqlalchemy it was caused by cascading on backrefs:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/session.html#backref-cascade

Turn it off on your backrefs so that you have to explicitly add things to the session